# What is the impact of a 'Coming Soon', holding page while redesigning the website?

Tags: seo, redesign

We're in the middle of redesigning our company website.

A request has come in from management to put in a holding page with basic contact info while the site is redeveloped.

Is this a good idea from an SEO standpoint?

What's the best way to implement this? I believe the temporary, simple HTML and CSS page would be uploaded to the server?

Comment: How long is the redevopment likely to take?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here...is development in a staging environment? If done on the current domain is the content on the current site removed? Is anything there?

Comment: What speaks against keeping the current content up until the new stuff is ready?